# character encoding in Wildfly

Tags: character-encoding, wildfly, wildfly-8

What is the default character encoding for sent requests in Wildfly?
Setting the encoding in contentType header of a request would insure that it will be used?

Thanks,

Tiberiu

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about two different encodings

- Request encoding: This is the encoding of parameters in the URL for example. By default is UTF-8 but if you want to change it to ISO-8859-1 (for example) it can be done  with `<http-listener url-charset="ISO-8859-1" .../>` in your configuration file under the undertow subsystem.
- Content Type encoding: This is the encoding that you are saying your files have and this is controlled by Content-Type http header and the charset parameter. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: To make things more clear, could you mention all the parts of a request that use request encoding and all parts that use content-type encoding